# Recursive nmake target

Tags: visual-studio, makefile, visual-c++, nmake

When recursively invoking nmake, via the $(MAKE) macro, how can I pass on the target specified on the command line to the new instance?

So, say I execute the following from the command line:

c:\nmake clean

I want the recursive call to nmake to pass the 'clean' target to the new nmake instance.

Answer (score 2):

you can write rule like this:

```
clean all:
    cd dir1 && $(MAKE) $*
    cd dir2 && $(MAKE) $*
```

$* will be substituted by target name ("clean" or "clean" in this example)

Comment: Just to comment a side effect. If no target is specified, it will first run clean, then proceed to run all. effectively serving as a rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but you normally have the rule by virtue of the fact that your executing a specific part of the makefile, such as:

```
clean:
    cd dir1 && $(MAKE) clean
    cd dir2 && $(MAKE) clean

all:
    cd dir1 && $(MAKE) all
    cd dir2 && $(MAKE) all
```

If you have some *other* setup in your makefile, your best bet is to post it so we can do  a better analysis.